# How can I use Windows Authentication to allow group members access to my web application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I under stand how to configure .NET Authorization under Windows Authentication to limit access to a website to specific users and groups.

However, for a web application, how do I set the database connection to impersonate the logged in user? The SQl database is on another server.

If this strictly IIS configuration? Code? Both? For an individual, I can add the credentials via the `<identity>` element, but what about impersonating AD group members?

The SQL Server is set up to to *only* allow connections from a specific group. The DBA set this up, I do not know the details.

Setting

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

and Integrated Security=true results in the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in
Integrated managed pipeline mode.
```

Comment: Why would you want your users to connect to the database?  Wouldn't a single service account be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes it would, but that is not how the DBA wants it done.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<identity impersonate="true" />`

in your web.config along with `Integrated Security=true;` in your connection string should do this for you.

It will be up to the database to discover if the Active Directory User supplied is in the appropriate AD Group.